# how to load another screen using a button in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm in process of developing a front-end web app using the python library `streamlit`, I create a page with `st.button` at the end or forms with submit button.

I'm trying to find a way when I click the button to jump to another python file I created but I can't find a solution.

Appreciate your feedback guys

Comment: Jump to another file? Can you explain it more?

Comment: yeah sorry, like i created several python files to make it easier file 1, 2, 3 and 4. i want to press a button in page 1 and on click page 2 will load and so on, i'm mentioning st.button and st.form submit button just in case the script is different

Comment: So you want to go to a different page after you click a button? So in your case your button will be a "enter the form" and your page will load the form?

Comment: im creating a welcome page and at the end displayed a button "click to proceed", so when the user presses the button, terms and conditions page will load, that is the process or flow for the web app

Comment: I would rethink the structure of your app. I would have one main python file for your app, that contains a sidebar for navigation or something. Then call your different python files depending on which item the user selects from the sidebar.

Comment: but the webpage im building is useless with a sidebar, i need to guide the user and not to give him the choice to select the pages he/she want.

Comment: You can have the code for each "page" in its own python file, optionally split over multiple functions in that file, then call this code from your main app file.

Comment: Appreciate if you can share a sample code, im new to coding and im still learning

Answer (score 2):

`streamlit-extras` has a bunch of small add-ons for Streamlit, including a switch page function. See the example app below for its use with a button.

https://pypi.org/project/streamlit-extras/

https://extras.streamlit.app/Switch%20page%20function

Comment: Thank you for the advice, those this library work with sidebar? and if at the end the only way to use this library is by adding a sidebar, can i hide from end user? meaning ill use it to switch between page without letting the end user browse freely. i just tried it and you can only navigate within the same code file. it weird to create a web app that you can't navigate within, although streamlit library is great but unfortunately if this feature is missing, it only for mobile apps then

Comment: Is it possible to import another library to navigate between pages like 'tkinter'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about navigating "within the same code file." There are two separate ideas here: how Streamlit implements multipage apps and how you can use a button to switch between those pages. By default, Streamlit will create navigation in the sidebar for multipage apps. You can look at packages like `st-pages` to modify this, or you can use CSS to hide the part of the sidebar if you are trying to manually create some other navigation. However, note that a user can always navigate to other pages through the url if they know the page name.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @MathCatsAnd, appreciate your time